# Tabbing in the \address section of the letter document class

Tags: horizontal-alignment, letters, tabbing

I am writing a letter using LaTeX's `letter` template, in which I include my e-mail address and phone numbers in the `\address` section. I would like to use icons from the `marvosym` package instead of writing "E-mail:" etc. Further, I would prefer for the e-mail address and phone numbers to be aligned as in a table.

Here is the code I try to use in the `\address` section:

```
\address{Kurt Han Peek \\ Piet Heinlaan 23 \\ 2341 SG  Oegstgeest \\ \begin{tabbing} \Letter \= \hspace{0.5em}\= kurt.peek@gmail.com \\ \Mobilefone \> \>06-14920959 \\ \Telefon \> \> (071) 517 7081 \end{tabbing}}
```

However, I get the error: `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` in TeXworks. I suspect the `tabbing` environment can't be used in the `\address`, because it does work in the main text. I have also tried using a `tabular` environment which works, but the cells have some "padding", so the marvosym icons then are not left-aligned with the address above.

Any ideas on how to solve this would be much appreciated.

P.S. For the sake of completeness, here is the complete LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{marvosym}   
\usepackage[pdfborder=0]{hyperref}

%\address{Kurt Han Peek \\ Piet Heinlaan 23 \\ 2341 SG  Oegstgeest \\ \Letter~\href{mailto:kurt.peek@gmail.com}{kurt.peek@gmail.com} \\ %\Mobilefone~0614920959 \\ \Telefon~  071 517 7081}

\address{Kurt Han Peek \\ Piet Heinlaan 23 \\ 2341 SG  Oegstgeest \\ \begin{tabbing} \Letter \= \hspace{0.5em}\= kurt.peek@gmail.com \\ \Mobilefone \> \>06-14920959 \\ \Telefon \> \> (071) 517 7081 \end{tabbing}}

\date{23 februari 2012}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{TNO \\ t.a.v. Maaike Blikslager \\ High Tech Campus 5 \\ 5656 AE  Eindhoven}
\opening{Beste ...,}
Graag wil ik solliciteren op de functie .... Het werk van de ...groep sluit goed aan bij interesses en carri\`eredoelen, ik en zou me verheugen om mijn kandidatuur persoonlijk met u te bespreken.

 \begin{tabular}{r@{\hspace{1em}}l}
  \Letter&\href{mailto:...@gmail.com}{...@gmail.com}\\                        
  \Mobilefone&06 14920959\\                          
  \Telefon&(071) 517 7081\\ \end{tabular}

\begin{tabbing}
\Letter \= \hspace{0.5em} \= kurt.peek@gmail.com \\
\Mobilefone \> \>06-14920959 \\
\Telefon \> \> (071) 517 7081
\end{tabbing}

Bedankt voor uw tijd, en ik verheug me op uw reactie.

\closing{Met vriendelijke groet, \\
%\fromsig{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{signature_kurt.jpg}} \\
\fromname{Kurt Peek}
}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "simulate" the `tabbing` behaviour using `\hbox to <length>{...}`, the following code is self-explanatory I hope:

```
\def\addresssymbol#1{\hbox to 1.2em{#1}} % <-- set a good length here

\address{Kurt Han Peek \\ Piet Heinlaan 23 \\ 2341 SG  Oegstgeest
\\ \addresssymbol{\Letter} kurt.peek@gmail.com
\\ \addresssymbol{\Mobilefone} 06-14920959
\\ \addresssymbol{\Telefon} (071) 517 7081
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm. Thanks, tohecz!

Comment: In that case you should mark the answer as accepted so that others see the problem was solved (see the [FAQ here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask))

Answer (score 2):

You can exploit the fact that a `minipage` containing only a `tabbing` environment will be as wide as necessary:

```
\address{Kurt Han Peek \\ Piet Heinlaan 23 \\ 2341 SG  Oegstgeest \\
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{tabbing}
  \Letter \= \hspace{0.5em}\= kurt.peek@gmail.com \\
  \Mobilefone \> \>06-14920959 \\
  \Telefon \> \> (071) 517 7081
  \end{tabbing}
  \end{minipage}}
```

But probably you can make better use of a `tabular` environment, that will free you from the necessity to guess at the symbols' widths:

```
\address{Kurt Han Peek \\ Piet Heinlaan 23 \\ 2341 SG  Oegstgeest \\
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{ }l}
  \Letter     & \texttt{kurt.peek@gmail.com} \\
  \Mobilefone & 06-14920959 \\
  \Telefon    & (071) 517 7081
  \end{tabular}}
```